# SSH in script without user interaction

Tags: ssh, scripting, authentication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to automate SSH login with password?](https://serverfault.com/questions/241588/how-to-automate-ssh-login-with-password)

Is there a way to call ssh in a bash script and automatically feed it the password for the account?

e.g if i type

```
ssh owen@myserver.com /settings
```

it prompts me for a password. I want to avoid that!

Answer (score 3):

You can use passwordless authentication with SSH using SSH Keys.

On your client machine, run

`ssh-keygen -t rsa`

This will generate 2 files `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, these are your public and private authentication keys.

Copy `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` from your client machine on to your target as `~/.ssh/authorized_keys2`.

You should now be able to access your server without needing a password.

Comment: Beat me to it!  +1 to you

Comment: It's easier to use "ssh-copy-id myserver" to install the public key onto the server