# How to auto login a .ssh server from a .ssh2 server?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I have a server `A` which `ssh-keygen` produce a `.ssh2` direcotry and `id_dsa_2048_a*` files
and a server `B` which `ssh-keygen` produce a `.ssh` directory and `id_rsa*` files
and a server `C` like `B`

How can auto login into `B` from `A`, or login into `A` from `B` (ssh without password)?

I can setup auto login from `B` to `C`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to automate SSH login with password?](http://serverfault.com/questions/241588/how-to-automate-ssh-login-with-password)

Comment: I've never dealt with trying to make ssh and ssh2 talk to each other myself but [I found this which may be helpful](http://burnz.wordpress.com/2007/10/17/how-to-make-ssh2-work-with-openssh/).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, just define the hosts in your `~.ssh/config` file:

```
Host hostB
    ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p hostA
```

Comment: There is no `.ssh` in hostA, so I assume I should do it in hostB?

Comment: As far as I understand you want to login from your workstation to serverB using serverA as a hop-station. If so, you need to modify the `.ssh/config` on your workstation.

Comment: Sorry, I mean directly..

Comment: So use `ssh-copy-id`